# docker-compose.yml - make network name configurable via environment variable

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a docker compose file with env variables for stage specific configurations. As long as env variables are used in values in docker-compose.yml everything is fine, but the problem is with the network name, since it's specified in the tag.

```
networks:
  mynetwork.${STAGE_NAME}:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: ${STAGE_NETWORK_PREFIX}.0/24
```

Any chance to get the network name `mynetwork.${STAGE_NAME}` configurable from outside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) installed (part or gnu `gettext`) you can use something like that:

```
export STAGE_NAME="xyz"
export STAGE_NETWORK_PREFIX="1.2.3.4"
docker-compose -f <(envsubst docker-compose.yml) ...
```

If your shell does not support process substitution, something like that would do the trick:

```
envsubst docker-compose.yml | docker-compose -f - ...
```

Answer (score 13):

It is possible via network name:

```
networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: ${STAGE_NAME}
```

where mynetwork - name "inside" stack

${STAGE_NAME} -name for other stacks/services/containers

See comment from docker capitan https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40819#issuecomment-618726892

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to directly control this, but I noticed that the folder containing the docker-compose.yml is used as prefix when creating the name for the docker network. My solution was to write a wrapper script for docker-compose which creates a new folder with the name of the stage

```
TARGET=/tmp/$STAGE_NAME

mkdir -p $TARGET

ln -sf $(pwd)/docker-compose.yml $TARGET/docker-compose.yml

cd $TARGET
docker-compose "$@"
cd -
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a switch -p in docker-compose which allow you to set this prefix to a custom value.